# Which to care for Ljung-Box test, X-Squared or P value?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Assuma we are working with `AirPassengers` data in R. To make it stationary, I have applied `log` and `diff`. After that I plot the data and it seems like a White noise.
[image: Differed after Logged]

Then I applied the test `Forecast::Box.test()` to be sure it is stationary. Here is my code and output of test.

```
> Box.test(diff(loglu), type="Ljung-Box")

    Box-Ljung test

data:  diff(loglu)
X-squared = 5.8263, df = 1, p-value = 0.01579
```

and with lag=20, because my workfellow said df should be 20 to compare X-squared values.

```
> Box.test(diff(loglu), lag = 20, type="Ljung-Box")

    Box-Ljung test

data:  diff(loglu)
X-squared = 217.1, df = 20, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

What should I interpret with those? Should I look for p-value or x-squared. OR both of them will already give me the same result?

Answer (score 1):

First, the Ljung-Box test is not a test for stationarity. It is a test for prove  if a serie is generated by a process of white noise. And this is a greater condition than stationarity. i.e. your time serie could be stationary but not white noise and the test could reject it.
Now, in your calculations remember that the test is a sumatory, so when you set lag = 1, the test use only the autocorrelation function at lag 1, and  when you set lag=20 the test use autocorrelations from 1 to 20, and this is the reason why tha value of chi-squared is greater in the second case.